# Custom Lambda resource stuck at CREATE_IN_PROGRESS while using Cloud Formation with Public subnet

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, amazon-vpc, amazon-aurora

I'm trying to create an AuroraDB cluster using cloud formation where I have one custom resource to rotate the secrets. It works fine with private subnet but when I try to create the same stack with public subnet the resource is stuck until CF timeout.
[image]

I checked cfnresponse module and the python module is returning the response properly.

```
cfnresponse.send(event, context, cfnresponse.SUCCESS, responseData, "CustomResourcePhysicalID")
```

You can find cloud formation code I'm using,

```
CreateSecretRotationLambdaFnTrigger:
Condition: IsNotUseDBSnapshot
Type: Custom::LambdaAPGSecretsManager
Version: "1.0"
Properties:
  ServiceToken: !GetAtt 'CreateSecretRotationLambdaFn.Arn'
  SecretsManagerEndpoint: !Sub 'https://secretsmanager.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com'
  SecretRotationLambdaFnName: !Sub 'SecretsManager-SecretRotationFn-${AWS::StackName}'
  SecretRotationLambdaStackName: !Sub '${AWS::StackName}-SecretRotationLambdaStack'
  SubnetIds: !Split [',', {'Fn::ImportValue': !Sub '${ParentVPCStack}-SubnetsPrivate'}]
  SecretRotationLambdaSG: !Split [',', {'Fn::ImportValue': !Sub '${ParentVPCStack}-SecretRotationLambdaSecurityGroup'}]
```

I'm using the below cloud formation template just modified the VPC template by deleting the private subnet and In the Aurora template, i changed subnets from private to public.
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/deploy-an-amazon-aurora-postgresql-db-cluster-with-recommended-best-practices-using-aws-cloudformation/

Please provide your inputs on this, Im wondering is it possible to create Custom lambda resources using cloud formation in a public subnet.

Thank you in advance

Comment: It is entirely possible. However, what is happening is a setting on your lambda requires some setting from your DB. Therefor it will sit and wait for the DB to finish initializing and be properly set up before continuing... and sometimes the cloud formation stack hangs anyways.  As a work around try creating just the db first then run the stack again with the lambda. That is not a perm solution but can let you verify the lambda deploys properly

Comment: Hi, thanks for your input however I tried creating Database first then updating the stack still the same issue. Custom Lambda resource stuck in creating in progress state until the stack timeout.  I will add templates I'm using in the above question

Comment: @DivyaGowda Can you also share the code for your custom resource lambda? And maybe the execution logs of a failed execution?

Comment: The error I'm getting is below,   CloudFormation did not receive a response from your Custom Resource. Please check your logs for requestId [96b0840c-04ae-48a9-af82-f08b619c11f5]. If you are using the Python cfn-response module,  you may need to update your Lambda function code so that CloudFormation can attach the updated version.